# git, Apache/httpd and LDAP - git client unable to access (error 500)

Tags: apache, redmine, httpd.conf, openldap, redmine-plugins

After the last CentOS 7's update we started to have the problems below when trying to clone a git repository.

**NOTE:** The infrastructure was built using **LDAP, Redmine, grack** and **git**.

Problem observed in the git client...

```
[some_user@some_user-pc ~]$ git clone http://some_url.foo/some_repo.git
Cloning into 'some_repo'...
Username for 'http://some_url.foo': some_git_user
Password for 'http://some_git_user@some_url.foo': 
fatal: unable to access 'http://some_url.foo/some_repo.git/': The requested URL returned error: 500
```

Problem observed on httpd/git server...

```
[root@hostname ~]# less +F /var/log/httpd/error_log
[...]
[Wed Jun 03 17:38:49.745122 2020] [authn_core:error] [pid 14382] [client 10.2.0.10:57884] AH01796: AuthType Basic configured without corresponding module
[...]
```

Apache/httpd configuration (Apache/httpd -> redmine -> crack -> git)...

```
[root@hostname ~]# cat /etc/httpd/conf.d/git.conf
<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName localhost.localdomain
    DocumentRoot /home/redmine/grack/public
    PerlLoadModule Apache::Redmine
    PerlLoadModule Authen::Simple::LDAP
    <Directory /home/redmine/grack/public>
        Options None
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    <Location "/">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Redmine git repositories"
        AuthUserFile /dev/null
        AuthBasicAuthoritative off
        Require valid-user
        PerlAccessHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::access_handler
        PerlAuthenHandler Apache::Authn::Redmine::authen_handler
        RedmineDSN "DBI:Pg:database=redmine;host=localhost;port=5432"
        RedmineDbUser "redmine" 
        RedmineDbPass "brlight" 
        RedmineGitSmartHttp yes
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

We are having serious difficulties in diagnosing the problem that is occurring, because the only error output we have is the one displayed in the "error_log".

This error seems strange to us because the module "mod_auth_basic.so" is being loaded and present in CentOS 7...

```
[root@hostname ~]# cat /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf
[...]
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
[...]
```

**What is going on?**

**NOTE:** Some sources report that this may be occurring due an update from Apache/httpd 2.2 to 2.4.

Comment: Check if `mod_auth_basic.so` binary present in the modules folder.

Comment: @Pandurang It's present! =D Thanks!

Comment: Check `apachectl -M or httpd -M` command to check the auth_basic module loaded or not in httpd.